# I have created popup menu with component as JCheckBox but I am not able to read its value when I click it

Tags: java

I have created popup menu with component as JCheckBox but I am not able to read it's value when I click it.

Using this code:

```
 JCheckBox cs_x=new JCheckBox(s1);
 popCourse.add(cs_x);
```

Comment: Post the entire code so people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean checked = cs_x.isSelected();
```

Is this what your are looking for?